# Hettest Not Appropriate for Robust Cluster

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

I am using stata, and running a regression with robust standard errors.
I want to test the Heteroscedasticity after running the regression with robust standard errors, and to compare this to before the regression was run using this facility?

Is this possible in anyway?

Comment: Calculating robust standard errors doesn't change the heteroscedasticity of anything.

Comment: _"4.1.1 Regression with Robust Standard Errors

The Stata regress command includes a robust option for estimating the standard errors using the Huber-White sandwich estimators. Such robust standard errors can deal with a collection of minor concerns about failure to meet assumptions, such as minor problems about normality, heteroscedasticity, or some observations that exhibit large residuals, leverage or influence. For such minor problems, the robust option may effectively deal with these concerns. "_ ([http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/reg/chapter4/statareg4.htm])

Comment: UCLA colleagues have an odd idea of "deal with". Previous statement is still true. At most, robust standard errors are more honest than the alternative.

Comment: Am i able to do some form of test for heteroschedasticity after using the robust standard error function that is the question now.

Comment: `robust` is an option, not a function. No; the Stata view is that makes no sense.

Comment: I understand its an option; but why does it make no sense?

Comment: Testing for heteroscedasticity and adjusting SEs for it are different questions. If you're asking why Stata made the option unavailable after using `robust`, I don't know as I did not write that command, but it is quite possibly because users such as yourself might think that using `robust` fixed the problem. As `hettest` is available without `robust`, why the concern? You are not missing anything that is defined.

Comment: How can I make sure that the robust standard errors are actually helping in "resolving" issues concerning the assumptions?

Comment: This looks the same question as before, so same answer. Robust SEs are more honest, so t and P-values may shift a bit. If the model is not a good idea, robust SEs don't fix that. You really have to read the Stata documentation or an econometrics text on robust SEs.